# Find convergence of an integral which is not decreasing.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $I=\int_0^{\pi/2} \log(\sin x)dx$. Then

1. I diverges at $x=0$.
2. I converges and is equal to $-\pi\log 2$.
3. I converges and is equal to $-\pi/2 \log 2$.
4. I diverges at $x=\pi/4$.

I found that value of integral is zero. 
and also that $\log(\sin x)$ is not a decreasing function, so we can not use integral test here. I am not able to think of applying any other series convergence test here.
Please, help me out.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/815571/integral-int-pi-2-0-ln-sin-x-dx?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is the third one.

We have that
$$I=\int_0^{\pi/2} \log(\sin x)dx=\int_0^{\pi/2} \log(\sin(\pi/2-x)dx=\int_0^{\pi/2} \log(\cos x)dx.$$
Moreover
$$\int_0^{\pi} \log(\sin x)dx=I+\int_{\pi/2}^{\pi} \log(\sin x)dx
\\=
I+\int_0^{\pi/2} \log(\sin (\pi-x))dx\\=
I+\int_0^{\pi/2} \log(\sin x)dx=2I.$$
Hence
$$2I=\int_0^{\pi/2} \log(\sin x)dx+\int_0^{\pi/2} \log(\cos x)dx=
\int_0^{\pi/2} \log(\sin x\cos x)dx\\=\int_0^{\pi/2} \log\left(\frac{\sin 2x}{2}\right)dx=\int_0^{\pi/2} \log(\sin 2x)dx-\int_0^{\pi/2} \log(2)dx\\
=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{\pi} \log(\sin t)dt-\frac{\pi}{2}\log(2)
=\frac{2I}{2}-\frac{\pi}{2}\log(2)$$
which implies that $I=-\frac{\pi}{2}\log(2)$.